# Reference to HTML elements in view, a convention?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm currently in the progress of learning Backbone.js and I'm using the book Developping Backbone Applications.

I have a questions about the reference to HTML elements and how they are stored. For example:

```
   initialize: function() {
        this.$input = this.$('#new-todo');
```

Here the HTML element with ID to-do is stored in the this.$input, why do we use the $ in front of input, is this merely a convention? If I change this.$input to this.input my code works fine. I find this confusing because the book states:

> The **view.$el property** is equivalent to **$(view.el)** and **view.$(selector)** is equivalent to **$(view.el).find(selector)**.

I would think that $(view.el) does something completely different than (view.el).

How is this.$input saved in Backbone.js? If I console.log it, it produces:

```
Object[input#new-todo property value = "" attribute value = "null"]
```

Could someone give me some insight? :)

Comment: `$(view.el)` is a call to the `$` function with `view.el` as an argument, `(view.el)` is simply `view.el` wrapped in grouping parentheses (not function calling parentheses). Keep in mind that `$` is a function provided by jQuery, `this.$el` is a view property provided by Backbone, `this.$` is a view function provided by Backbone, and that a dollar sign is just a character that is valid in JavaScript identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using $ infront of a variable name is just a naming convention. It helps developer in distinguishing variable holding jQuery objects from others.
- view.$el is a helper variable provided by Backbone, so that we can use it directly, instead of explicitly forming the jQuery object. Hence view.$el is equivalent to $(view.el).

view.$el is assigned in setElement method:

```
setElement: function(element, delegate) {
   // Some code
   this.$el = element instanceof Backbone.$ ? element : Backbone.$(element);
   // Some code
}
```

Backbone.$ is reference to $ global variable exported by jQuery.

- view.$(selector) is a method defined in View. It's definition does exactly same as $(view.el).find(selector)

  $: function(selector) {
      return this.$el.find(selector);
  }